# Converting long dataframe and extracting string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have Dataframe like this:

```
    Date A_2002 B_2003 C_2004 D_2005 Type
03-2002   20     30      12     42    X
04-2002   12     321     12     23    X
03-2002   10     31      2      3     Y
```

I want to convert it to long version and extract the string type from it so the end result would be this:

```
   Date NewCol Extracted Type Value
03-2002 A       2002      X    20
03-2002 B       2003      X    30
03-2002 C       2004      X    12
03-2002 D       2005      X    42
04-2002 A       2002      X    12
04-2002 B       2003      X    321
04-2002 C       2004      X    12
04-2002 D       2005      X    23
03-2002 A       2002      Y    10
03-2002 B       2003      Y    31
03-2002 C       2004      Y    2
03-2002 D       2005      Y    3
```

So the end result will convert value from column name into tow new values and melt the data as seen above. Is it possible with pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do `stack` after `set_index` and `str.split`:

```
m = df.set_index(['Date','Type'])
m.columns = m.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
out = (m.stack([0,1]).rename('Value').reset_index()
     .rename(columns={'level_2':'NewCol','level_3':'Extracted'}))
```

---

```
       Date Type NewCol Extracted  Value
0   03-2002    X      A      2002   20.0
1   03-2002    X      B      2003   30.0
2   03-2002    X      C      2004   12.0
3   03-2002    X      D      2005   42.0
4   04-2002    X      A      2002   12.0
5   04-2002    X      B      2003  321.0
6   04-2002    X      C      2004   12.0
7   04-2002    X      D      2005   23.0
8   03-2002    Y      A      2002   10.0
9   03-2002    Y      B      2003   31.0
10  03-2002    Y      C      2004    2.0
11  03-2002    Y      D      2005    3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) here:

```
out = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Type'])

(out.assign(**out.pop('variable')
                 .str.split('_', expand=True)
                 .rename(columns=dict(zip(range(2), ['NewCol', 'Extracted'])))))

       Date Type  value NewCol Extracted
0   03-2002    X     20      A      2002
1   04-2002    X     12      A      2002
2   03-2002    Y     10      A      2002
3   03-2002    X     30      B      2003
4   04-2002    X    321      B      2003
5   03-2002    Y     31      B      2003
6   03-2002    X     12      C      2004
7   04-2002    X     12      C      2004
8   03-2002    Y      2      C      2004
9   03-2002    X     42      D      2005
10  04-2002    X     23      D      2005
11  03-2002    Y      3      D      2005
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `pd.wide_to_long`. Once nice thing is that wide_to_long converts the `'Extracted'` column to `int64`, though we need to manually specify the stubs and `value` gets upcast to float.

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['Date', 'Type'], j='Extracted',
                      stubnames=list('ABCD'), sep='_')
        .rename_axis('NewCol', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .rename('value')
        .reset_index())
#       Date Type  Extracted NewCol  value
#0   03-2002    X       2002      A   20.0
#1   03-2002    X       2003      B   30.0
#2   03-2002    X       2004      C   12.0
#3   03-2002    X       2005      D   42.0
#4   04-2002    X       2002      A   12.0
#5   04-2002    X       2003      B  321.0
#6   04-2002    X       2004      C   12.0
#7   04-2002    X       2005      D   23.0
#8   03-2002    Y       2002      A   10.0
#9   03-2002    Y       2003      B   31.0
#10  03-2002    Y       2004      C    2.0
#11  03-2002    Y       2005      D    3.0

df.dtypes
#Date          object
#Type          object
#Extracted      int64
#NewCol        object
#value        float64
```